# Is it possible to directly 'convert' a google drive image url in Imagemagick?

Tags: google-drive-api, imagemagick

I have had a good search around for this, but cannot find a concrete answer. I have been trying to run the convert command against a url for an image I have stored on google drive, in a public folder.
I have been able to get this to work if I wget the url with -qO- and pipe this to convert- e.g.

```
wget 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ydsWevwDxARqrabo5yZEYozez0eZK4K1' -qO- |  convert - -resize 100x100 MGFIN01.png
```

Ideally I would prefer to be able to directly run the url through convert:

```
convert https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ydsWevwDxARqrabo5yZEYozez0eZK4K1 -resize 100x100 MGFIN01.png
```

With the ultimate intention of creating an html image map like: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#html therefore requiring a list of urls and names (I can probably work this out once I have resolved the url part)

I am on Ubuntu with imagemagick 6.9. I see in delegates.xml that I have this:

```
<delegate decode="https" command="&quot;curl&quot; -s -k -L -o &quot;%o&quot; &quot;https:%M&quot;"/>
```

Also tried the download with curl and options and that also worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on ImageMagick 6.9.10.97 Q16 Mac OSX. Put the URL in double quotes. You may also have to edit your policy.xml file to give permission for HTTPS. See policy.xml at https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

```
convert "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ydsWevwDxARqrabo5yZEYozez0eZK4K1" -resize 100x100 MGFIN01.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Fred. Success. I edited the policy.xml from:
`<policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />`
to
`<policy domain="delegate" rights="read" pattern="https" />` and it worked OK.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found and fixed the issue.

Comment: is this still working for you ? just tried  `convert "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ydsWevwDxARqrabo5yZEYozez0eZK4K1" -resize 100x100 MGFIN01.png
` and getting error `convert-im6.q16: not authorized `HTTPS' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1717.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open file `': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `MGFIN01.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.`

Comment: You have to edit the policy.xml file to permit the use of HTTPS. So give it read permission and uncomment it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a tidier response than possible in comments:

Open policy.xml

```
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Scroll down to find:

```
<policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
```

Edit this to show:

```
<policy domain="delegate" rights="read" pattern="https" />
```

Save (CTRL+X, Y)

Run convert command again. Tada.

Comment: The `https` instead of `HTTPS` appears to be important. Tried with `HTTPS` first and it didn't work.  Also: find the `policy.xml` file on your system:
`sudo find /etc/ -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "policy.xml"`